# Pulling multiple calendar events from gCal using Sheets API

Tags: google-apps-script

I followed this example (http://www.cloudbakers.com/blog/export-google-calendar-entries-to-a-google-spreadsheet) to pull events from Google Calendar into Spreadsheets using the Google Apps Script.

However, I'm trying to pull in multiple calendars and created a loop:

```
var email_list = ['email1', 'email2', 'email3']
email_list.forEach(function (email) {
  var mycal = email
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal)
  ...
})
```

However the way Google Apps Script works is that it starts from Row2 every time. Is there anyway to append each event?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of two ways on how to do this. First is, as you want it to, you can use [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#appendrowrowcontents). It automatically selects the last row and rights to it with the data provided.

Second, is still using the original logic, starting at Row 2. Instead of going through the adding of the events to spreadsheet code for every calendar, what you could do is simply iterate over all the calendars first and consolidate all the matching events, then iterate over the events and add them to the spreadsheet.